# Using multiple fonts for tick labels on the same axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap

I have to use characters from English and Hindi on x and y axes to display the confusion matrix. Since the default font is sans-serif, I set the Hindi font as:

```
plt.xticks(fontname='Lohit Devanagari')
plt.yticks(fontname='Lohit Devanagari')
```

I also enable ticks labels on both sides of the axes:

```
ax.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelright=True, labelsize=6)
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
```

[image]

Expected outcome

I expected to get Hindi and English characters properly displayed on both the axes, but as observed, English is properly rendered on above and right axes and Hindi is displayed on left and below axes.

Matplotlib version: 2.2.2 
Matplotlib backend `(print(matplotlib.get_backend()))`: TkAgg 
Python version: 3.5.2 
Other libraries: seaborn==0.8.1

I installed matplotlib inside a virtualenv using pip.

Kindly provide your suggestions to render both the fonts properly on all axes. It will be a great help!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a [mcve]

Comment: I will just repeat my comment below your [GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11167) here: In how far is this specific to a confusion matrix? Would it be possible to provide a [mcve] (including a guide on which font to use on a standard system or where to get a font that shows that problem)?

Comment: This problem may be solved after the PR for this issue is merged. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18883